# Homestead Laravel 5.3.29 No input file specified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Stack:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Laravel 5.3.29
- Vagrant 1.9.1
- Homestead

I'm running: `vagrant up` from ~/Homestead/

This is my yaml from ~/.homestead/:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public/

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

I've also edited /etc/hosts: 
192.168.10.10  homestead.app

In my local folder "~/Code/blog/public" and in vagrant ssh "home/vagrant/code/blog/public" - exists.
When I go to http://homestead.app - it shows me this error: No input file specified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try by removing the trailing slash from `/home/vagrant/code/blog/public`. and the error means nginx document root is not correct for homestead.app.

Comment: @Ramer Is this the first time you edited `Homestead.yaml` or are you trying to update an already once configured `Homestead.yaml` file. If you're trying the latter one you need to do `Vagrant reload --provision`.

Answer (score 0):

nginx cannot find your index.php because the path to your public folder has a trailing slash.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public/ <-- remove this trailing slash

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```